# How to pass 2D char array to another function by reference

Tags: c, pointers, dev-c++

I want to pass my 2D char array to another function by reference. I did same thing with my int ** it works perfectly. But when it come to char ** same method is broken. I try too many things. I read almost every question but I couldn't see my case.

First of all I have a one char ** which is set to NULL and I pass it to another function by reference.

This my main function

```
int main(){
    int **recommendU2 = NULL;
    char **bookNames = NULL;
    
    readFromCsv(&recommendU2,&bookNames,&bookCount,&userCount);

    printf("\n user[2][3] = %d \n",recommendU2[2][3]); //this works 
    printf("\n bookNames[1] = %s \n,bookNames[1]); //this doesn't works
    
    return 0;
}
```

Here is my another function which reads from csv and process this data. It is do it purpose without and issue. It reads from csv and read data line by line and process it without a problem. But I can't access my char ** data. But I can reach my int ** data. I didn't notice any difference between too.

```
void readFromCsv(int ***user,char ***bookNames,int *bookCount,int *userCount){
    FILE * fpointer;
    int lineCount = 0;  
    int count;
    int sizes[3];  
    fpointer = fopen("recdataset.csv","r");
    char recommendationSheet[RECOMMENDATIONSIZE];

    while(fgets(recommendationSheet,RECOMMENDATIONSIZE,fpointer)){
        if(lineCount>1){
            //this part is not important for this question
        }
        else if(lineCount == 0){
            userArraysMemoryAllocate(recommendationSheet,user,nuser,bookNames,&sizes[0]);
            (*user)[2][3] = 4;
            //I can access this user data both within this function and main function
        }
        else if(lineCount == 1){
            //actually I send variables to another function which named getBookNames() but when I can't reach data I suspect it and move it's code to here. But this doesn't make any different too.

            char *p = recommendationSheet;
            int j = 0;
            int i = 0;
            while(1) {
                char *p2 = strchr(p, ';');
                if(p2 != NULL)
                    *p2 = '\0';
                if(i>0)
                    strcpy((*bookNames)[i],p);
                printf("\n Book Name is = %s \n",(*bookNames)[i]); //This line works read bookNames correctly
                i++;
                if(p2 == NULL)
                    break;
                p = p2 + 1;
            }
            printf("\nbookName = %s \n",(*bookNames)[2]); //this line doesn't work
        } 
        lineCount++;
    }
    fclose(fpointer);
}
```

I couldn't make it work. I tried so many variations but none of them works. If you have any solution or any other idea to make this work I will appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Note : This program is too long to put here. So I only copied problematic part here. This includes so many functions calls. So If you don't understand anywhere please say it and I could add this part of code too.

**Update**

I add memory allocate function to readfromCsv function too. Here is the code. My problem still occurs. I thought I fixed it but it cause unnormal behaviour.

```
void readFromCsv(int ***user,char ***bookNames,int *bookCount,int *userCount,){
FILE * fpointer;
int lineCount = 0;  
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
int len;
int count;
int sizes[3];
fpointer = fopen("recdataset.csv","r");
char recommendationSheet[RECOMMENDATIONSIZE];

while(fgets(recommendationSheet,RECOMMENDATIONSIZE,fpointer)){
    len = strlen(recommendationSheet);
    if( recommendationSheet[len-1] == '\n' )
        recommendationSheet[len-1] = 0;
    if(lineCount>1){
        //not important
    }
    else if(lineCount == 0){
        char *p = recommendationSheet;
        i = 0;
        j = 0;
        int row = 0;
        int col = 0;
        
        while(i<3) {
            char *p2 = strchr(p, ';');
            if(p2 != NULL)
                *p2 = '\0';
            if(i==0){
                row = atoi(p);  
                col = row;          
                if((*bookNames = (char**)malloc(row * sizeof(char*))) == NULL){
                printf("\nMemory allocation problem \n");
                exit(0);
                }
                for(j = 0; j < row; ++j){
                    if(((*bookNames)[j] = (char*)malloc(50 * sizeof(char))) == NULL){
                        printf("\nMemory allocation problem \n");
                        exit(0);
                    }
                }
            }
            else if(i==1){
                row = atoi(p);
                if((*user = (int**)malloc(row * sizeof(int*))) == NULL){
                    printf("\nMemory allocation problem \n");
                    exit(0);
                }           
                for(j = 0; j < row; ++j){
                    if(((*user)[j] = (int*)malloc(col * sizeof(int))) == NULL){
                        printf("\nMemory allocation problem \n");
                        exit(0);
                    }
                }           
            }
            else if(i==2){
                row = atoi(p);
                if((*nuser = (int**)malloc(row * sizeof(int*))) == NULL){
                    printf("\nMemory allocation problem \n");
                    exit(0);
                }           
                for(j = 0; j < row; ++j){
                    if(((*nuser)[j] = (int*)malloc(col * sizeof(int))) == NULL){
                        printf("\nMemory allocation problem \n");
                        exit(0);
                    }
                }
            }
            sizes[i] = row;
            i++;
            if(p2 == NULL)
                break;
            p = p2 + 1;
        }
        (*user)[2][3] = 4; // this works still here and main function
    }
    else if(lineCount == 1){
        char *pMemory = recommendationSheet;
        j = 0;
        i = 0;
        while(1) {
            char *p2 = strchr(pMemory, ';');
            if(p2 != NULL)
                *p2 = '\0';
            if(i>0)
                (*bookNames)[i] = pMemory;
            printf("\n %d. Book name is = %s \n",i,(*bookNames)[i]); // works perfectly
            i++;
            if(p2 == NULL)
                break;
            pMemory = p2 + 1;
        }
    } 
    lineCount++;
}

fclose(fpointer);
}
```

Still I couldn't access my char ** from my main function. I add memory allocation process. I though I fixed it but problem occurs again without any change. I didn't understand the problem at all.

Comment: In the `readFromCsv` function `*user` is a *null pointer*. You can't dereference it as it will lead to undefined behavior and very likely crashes. It seems like the `readFromCsv` function should dynamically allocate memory for `*user` and `*bookNames`.

Comment: I think you need to show the code for `userArraysMemoryAllocate` if that is allocating the memory for `*bookNames` and `(*bookNames)[foo]` (for all `foo`).

Comment: Yes it does that. I didn't put it here because this part is not problematic. But actually I should say that sorry. It dynamically allocate memory for **user and **bookNames in userArraysMemoryAllocate() function.

Comment: Thank you all , I solved my problem. I didn't know exact reason for that but I add solution to end of my question. Thanks again.

Comment: The problem with `strcpy((*bookNames)[i],p)` was probably that `(*bookNames)[i]` wasn't properly allocated. However with `(*bookNames)[i] = p` you have a different problem: You make all elements of `*bookNames` point to the ***local*** array `recommendationSheet`. Those pointers will become invalid as soon as the `readFromCsv` function returns and the life-time of `recommendationSheet` ends.

Comment: You probably need to replace `strcpy((*bookNames)[i], p);` with `(*bookNames)[i] = strdup(p);`. But `strdup` is not in the C standard, so you might need to roll your own version of `strdup`, or replace the code with `(*bookNames)[i] = malloc(strlen(p) + 1);` `strcpy((*bookNames)[i], p);`. (Error checks for `malloc` or `strdup` returning `NULL` have been omitted.)

Comment: I thought I fixed the issue but problem still occurs. I add memory allocation code too. Could you please check it ? Am I doing something wrong ? int ** works , char ** doesn't I didn't get it at all.

Comment: @IanAbbott Thank you very much. I changed this line to "(*bookNames)[i] = strdup(p);" and I can access it from my main function now. I add my memory allocation process to my question. Could you look at it ? Do I need to do any other malloc for it ? Or is it enough ?

Comment: OT:  regarding: `if( recommendationSheet[len-1] == '\n' )
        recommendationSheet[len-1] = 0;`   this is not a reliable method for elimination of a trailing newline.  Suggest: `recommendtionSheet[ strcspn( recommendationSheet, "\n" ) ] = '\0';`

Comment: OT: regarding parameters like: `int ***user,char ***bookNames` Please read [three star programmer](https://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer)

Comment: @user3629249 Thanks for suggestion. Could you tell me how "strcspn" works ? If a line doesn't include "\n" is this function work properly or give any error ? And thanks for this three star info but actually I am a android programmer. I am not very familiar with C. How can I do that desired case without *** ?

Comment: *Could you tell me how "strcspn" works ? If a line doesn't include "\n" is this function work properly or give any error ?*  if the string does not contain '\n' then the trailing NUL char will be overlayed with a NUL char. I.E. no problem.  [man page for strcsp](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcspn)